# Codeblocks Permision denied after update from 12.10 to 13.04

Tags: 13.04, compiling

When I try to compile it says

```
sh: 1: /media/user/Linux/test/bin/Debug/test: Permission denied
```

I did not have this problem with Ubuntu 12.10

I have just started to use Ubuntu so....

Comment: Is /media/user/Linux/ a NTFS (or FAT) partition? I can't explain exactly why this happen, but I've seen a lot of "Permission denied" errors when compiling source code in a NTFS filesystem. Try to move the code to an EXT partition.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved by making the NTFS partition executable You find these steps if you search for *How to get permission to compile a C program from a NTFS Hard Drive.*

Follow these steps to make a NTFS partition executable:

1. Open a terminal and type

   ```
   sudo blkid -c /dev/null
   ```

   This command allow you to identify your NTFS drive and your UUID number. Example :

   ```
   /dev/sdb1: LABEL="my_label" UUID="xxx" TYPE="ntfs"
   ```
2. Open the `/etc/fstab` file from terminal typing

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
   ```
3. Don't edit the existing lines, but add new one at the end like this example:

   ```
   UUID=xxx /media/my_label ntfs-3g defaults,auto,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=002 0 0
   ```

   NOTE: Replace the UUID number and the mounting point `/media/my_label` according to your situation!
4. Save the file and close the text editor.
5. Enter the next command in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo mount -a
   ```

   After I have done this it said that it can not be mounted, but after I have restarted Ubuntu it worked.
6. And restart Ubuntu. Done

Now, every time you mount your NTFS partition, you will be able to run executable files.

Answer (score 0):

Change the project directory to your Home folder like `/home/test`